# quick question: html character entities

Tags: html, formatting

I'm just curious if it's in any way frowned upon to use html character entities in the title attribute of an anchor tag or in the img alt attribute? I'm using jQuery to pull/place info from the attributes, and it's very convenient in this application to apply formatting in this way--

```
&lt;em&gt;TEXT&lt;/em&gt;
```

--within the title attribute, for example. It seems to validate just fine but feels a little dirty for some reason. Thanks for any feedback here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a bit messy to me.  Any plugin that requires you to store data in a HTML attribute that was meant for something else, is a bad plugin.

The title tag is supposed to include a descriptive title, plain and simple.

Use $.data instead or html5 data attributes.  Better yet, the plugin should allow you to pass any value or a function, and go from there.

Comment: ok that totally makes sense; but just to be more clear in this instance, the information being pulled from the title tag is descriptive in nature, I simply want to easily apply formatting to portions of the descriptive text-- via the character entities-- i.e. bold and italicize one portion of the string, that's it; so that would reside within the intended parameters of the attribute, no? also curious with respect to Quentin's response, if this would present an issue for screen readers?

Comment: If you're ok with users seeing "&lt;em&gt;" when they hover, then I guess it could work.  Do you have any control over that back-end?  The best solution (and no more difficult) is to render the title/alt tags as plain text that could be read by any screen reader, but render the special character text as an HTML5 data attribute, since after all, that is why they exist.

Comment: ok, thanks for the insights. I do have control over the backend-- it's just one of a billion jQuery lighbox plugins-- although my jQuery skills are nascent. I'll look into the HTML5 data attribute as one of my goals with this project is to employ as many HTML5 features as possible, ie. semantic markup and such.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm just curious if it's in any way frowned upon to use html character entities in the title attribute of an anchor tag or in the img alt attribute?

No, it isn't.

> `&lt;em&gt;TEXT&lt;/em&gt;`

Using characters to draw decorative arrows, on the other hand, is. They look weird and, when read with a screen reader, sound even weirder.

> I'm using jQuery to pull/place info from the attributes

That's fine, so long as you remember that the attributes are there for a purpose and you use them for that purpose and not as a general data store.

If you want a general data store then [HTML 5 has `data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. Html entities were simply a way to code-ify characters that could be confused by the parser, or characters that did not appear in the ASCII set, like 3/4.